# Replace Space with Plus in PHP Array

Tags: php, arrays

I get array $allprofessions from database

```
Array ( [0] => Html css js [2] => web developer [3] => fitness trainer)
```

and I want to replace all spaces in array ' ' with '+'. I want to get value in array similar to

web+developer

Html+css+js

fitness+trainer

So I try

```
$allprofessions = array_filter($array_profession_from_db);
foreach($allprofessions as $key=>$allprofessionlist){
    $allprofessions[$key] = str_replace("+", " ",  $allprofessionlist[$key]);
};
print_r($allprof);
```

and I get an error

Comment: "_and I get an error_" _What_ error do you get?

Comment: _"and I get an error"_ - and which one ...? Don't let us guess, or have to test your code - quote error messages, verbatim!

Comment: Also, what's the _purpose_ of this? Should you intend to use those values in an URL context later on: `urlencode` and `rawurlencode` exist.

Comment: Why do you want to replace spaces with plusses? That smells like URL encoding, in which case you'd be better off using a function designed for that.

Comment: `str_replace("+", " "` — You should check the manual and see which order the arguments should go in.

Comment: `print_r($allprof);` Where is `$allprof` defined? Also, `$allprofessionlist[$key]` doesn't seem to exist

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, $allprof is not defined. Second I recommend you to check [srt_replace documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace.php)

Watch out with your $allprofessionlist var, because is not a list, is the current value of the iteration.

I think what you want is this, assuming I have an array with values with " ":

```
$allprofessions = array('zzz x', 'bbbb aaa');
foreach($allprofessions as $key=> $item){
    $allprofessionsList[$key] = str_replace(" ", "+",  $item);
};
print_r($allprofessionsList);
```

I hope that helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this will solve it out for you and let me know if you have questions.

```
$newArray = array();

foreach($array_profession_from_db as $allprofessionlist){
    $newArray[] = str_replace(' ', '+', $allprofessionlist);
};

print_r($newArray);
```